# Undoing the Last Installed Windows Updates via Command Line

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2003, uninstall, windows-update

Using the command line, how can I undo the last installed windows updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Updates should create a [System Restore Point before installing the update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so you should be able to roll back to that.

[How to restore Windows XP to a previous state](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306084) describes the steps to rollback to a restore point and although is obviously Windows XP specific, the process should be similar for Server 2003.

Note that you can launch the System Restore GUI from a command prompt

```
%systemroot%\system32\restore\rstrui.exe
```

but I'm not sure if it's possible to execute an actual restore this way.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [wuinstall](http://wuinstall.com). It is a command line tool for managing Windows updates.
Although there is no explicit command for undoing the last update, you can uninstall updates in several ways. The basic command is:

```
wuinstall /uninstall ...
```

There are many ways to select the updates to be uninstalled. For example:
`/severity`, `/product`, `/match "regular expression"`, `/nomatch`, etc.

The command for uninstalling an update with a known KB number would be:

```
wuinstall /uninstall /match KB1234567
```

For more info, see [here](http://help.wuinstall.com/en/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

`wuinstall` is not part of system commands, you can use

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:<number>
```

and to see man page try `wusa /?`.

Comment: Check [this answer about `wusa`](http://superuser.com/a/491524/257269) and [the reference inside](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/109213-windows-update-uninstall-console-level.html).  Further [reference about `WUInstall`](http://juventusitprofessional.blogspot.ru/2013/12/windows-powershell-managing-windows.html). Please add some reference too to make your answer more complete.